# What happens when stats go above the "max"?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I've read on some guides that certain stats have a max (usually 50). My apprentice is level 37 and has a tower damage stat of over 100: about 60 on the character and 40+ on equipment. Usually level ups take me by surprise, and I haven't had a chance to confirm what's happening to my tower damage when my stats go up.

Do bonuses to these stats apply indefinitely? If not, what is the hard cap? Is there a certain point at which I should stop adding points to tower damage, tower attack rate, etc.?

Comment: The current soft cap/max you can add yourself on a single stat is 120 points. I'm not sure if a hard cap exists on the points you can get from equipment. Regarding when you should stop adding points, that's entirely subjective based on how you want to build your character.

Comment: When I asked whether I should stop adding points, I meant in terms of "points above X will have no effect"

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes there is no hard cap.  I've seen an apprentice with 9999 tower stats before on open and a single magic missile tower was enough to hold a lane.

Comment: @yx. Aren't magic missle towers considered electrical damage? Wouldn't electricity-immune mobs make it impossible for a single magic missle tower enough to hold a lane?

Comment: @Beofett nope, MM towers aren't elemental.

Comment: @yx. Wow, not sure how I missed that. I'll need to start putting them back into heavier use!

Comment: There is actually diminishing return on all the stats, but I don't think there is "a point of no more effect".

Comment: @Tudwell Also, many of the guides out there are for the mobile version, where your stats apparently max out at 60 instead of 120, so keep that in mind when reading them! Trying to find PC guides has caused me a lot of frustration. :(

Comment: @FAE: The easiest way for me to keep up with the changes like that is to hit up the Trendy forums, where they've got subforums for each platform.

Answer (score 5):

The max cap is just for what you can raise the stat to via leveling, not the max it can actually be. Your item bonuses and such will allow you to go beyond it and is where character customization comes into play in an extended format.

Hope this helps!